# Using std::unique_ptr with CComObject

Tags: c++, c++11, com, atl

I have an ATL COM object `CFoo` with an interface `IFoo` and I use the COM factory to create an instance of this as follows:

```
CComObject<CFoo>* ret;
HRESULT hr;
if (FAILED(hr = CComObject<CFoo>::CreateInstance(&ret)){
    return hr;
}
```

After this, some boilerplate code follows where, essentially, I attempt to get the `IFoo` interface and return that. The key thing is though is that, unless I'm careful, I suspect I'll leak a `CComObject<CFoo>` instance if any of this boilerplate code throws an exception.

So I thought about writing, just after the code above,

```
std::unique_ptr<CComObject<CFoo>> ret_g(ret);
```

which, of course, means that `ret_g` will own the pointer. Then, from a memory perspective, I'm safe. But then I need to remember to give back ownership if I manage to return an `IFoo` since the `std::unique_ptr` destructor will delete my object. **Boom!** (I can do that with a call to `ret_g.release()`.

ATL was designed pre C++11. Which makes me think there is a better way of addressing these issues already built into ATL. Is there?

Comment: Better way would be to use something designed for ATL. Use `CComPtr`. I don't think your `unique_ptr` solution works, because you need `ret->Release()` (or something similar) to be called, instead of `delete ret`, which is what the `unique_ptr` will do.

Comment: This blog may resolve your problem:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/03/28/api-problems-ccomobject-createinstance.aspx

Comment: Why not use `CComPtr` which is designed for exactly this?